# Is there any foster-Lyapunov criterion for time varying Markov processes?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes, stability

Suppose I have 2 Markov processes with transition kernels Q_1(y|x) and Q_2(y|x). Suppose i also have Lyapunov functions V_1, V_2 for these processes w.r.t. a common set, i.e. there exists a compact set S such that for x outside S, the drift of the respective Lyapunov function is bounded above by a negative number for both the processes.

Now suppose I construct a new Markov processes by using Q_1 kernel at odd times and Q_2 kernel at even times.
Can I guarantee stability of this new process in the set S i.e. can I construct a Lyapunov function for this third process on set S such that the drift of the Lyapunov function is negative outside the set S?

Comment: Drift bounded below or above?

Comment: above-- corrected!

Comment: And don’t you want the negative drift outside $S$?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foster%27s_theorem

Please add a reference to which version of Foster Theorem you are using.

Comment: We only assume negative drift outside the compact set S. There is a verison of Foster-Lyapunov Theorem in Meyn and Tweedie that guarantees stability of such processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is negative- the combined process obtained by alternating the kernels need not be stable.

On the state space 
$\Lambda=\{(x,y) \in {\bf Z}^2 : x,y\ge 0\}$ (The non-negative quadrant in the square lattice) consider the following two kernels. Along the two axes both kernels will send the particle toward the origin. Elsewhere, $Q_1$ will have a strong drift right and a weak drift down, while $Q_2$ will have a strong drift up and a weak drift left. Each of these kernels will send any particle to the axes, and then to zero, but alternating them will yield a drift up and right.

Formally, for $x,y>0$ let
$Q_1((x',y')|(x,y))=1/2$ iff $x'=x+1$ and $(y'=y \, $ or $\, y'=y-1)$.

Also for $x,y>0$ let $Q_2((x',y')|(x,y))=1/2$ iff $y'=y+1$ and 
$(x'=x\, $ or $\, x'=x-1)$.

If $x>0$ then $Q_i((x-1,0)|(x,0))=1$. If $y>0$ then $Q_i((0,y-1)|(0,y)=1$. Finally,
 $S=\{(0,0)\}$  is absorbing for both kernels: $Q_i((0,0)|(0,0))=1$.

Then $L_1(x,y)=x+4y$ is a Lyapunov function for $Q_1$ with drift at most $-1$ off  $S$. Similarly,  $L_2(x,y)=4x+y$ is a Lyapunov function for $Q_2$ off $S$. However, alternating $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ yields a process that tends to infinity from any initial lattice point $(x,y)$ with $x,y>1$.

Comment: Thanks! That is very helpful.
I believe this is also related to "Parrondo's paradox".